# Android application name error

Tags: android

I tried to build an android application, when I use non-english langues like persian as name of application it causes this error `AndroidManifest.xml file missing` and no manifest builds but when I use english it works successful, why?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file? At least the relevant part..

Comment: @Arman: I posted it before `AndroidManifest.xml file missing`

Comment: @krsteeve: I said it creates no manifest file, what do you mean by posting it?

Comment: That's the only one? Can you post your manifest file? Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: @Amir you must have an AndroidManifest.xml ... it will be at the top level of your project, beside the `src` and `bin` folders

Comment: As I build the project it shows me that error in console when I retry building same project with english name it works fine

Comment: @krsteeve: my problem is that I have no manifest file if I had it there was no error

Comment: @AmirSadegh what the guys are confused about your explanation. Is that AndroidManifest is generated by the programmer and compiled by the SDK. If there's an error the SDK won't generate your app, but the AndroidManifest.xml should still exist because you have to create it yourself manually.

Answer (score 1):

at the top of every XML file in Android you'll see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So first I ask you: is persian included in `utf-8` encoding?

I had a quick look on this link http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and it seems to be me that's a `no` but I'm no language expert and that table might show persian as one of it related or base languages (like portuguese uses latin set)

If persian is not available in the `utf-8` your best option to try to get this name in the app name is to create a strings_per.xml (inside the /values/ folder) and in there you put a different encoding and the string you need for the app name.

note that I tried to isolate the problematic variable in its own file because I'm not sure it would be a good idea to mix it with the rest of the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Farsi IS included in UTF8.
You need to add a string in strings.xml in /res/values. 
Then define a farsi name there.
Your string.xml will look like this:

```
<string name="app_name">اسم اپ</string>
<string name="title_tab1">تماس با ما</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

And you will reference it in you manifest.xml like this:

android:label="@string/app_name"

But remember: Farsi characters are not perfectly shown in android 2.2 and 2.3. 
The characters are displayed separately. For later androids this is not an issue.